# Unable to load the MySQL JDBC connection on Mac

Tags: java, mysql, macos, jdbc, toad

I have installed MySQL on Mac OSX Yosemite 10.10.2. It installed ok and i was able to start it from System preference, but JDBC connection is not working, i have correct driver jar included in classpath. I have tried to connect using Toad App as well but it doesn't work. I have attached the Exception screenshot, any suggestions?

Configuration properties file looks like following:

```
jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/nadeem_smartclogs?socket=/mysql/socket
jdbc.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.username=root
jdbc.password=
```

spring context related part

```
 <bean id="propertyConfigurer"
          class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
          p:location="/WEB-INF/mysqlConfig.properties" />


    <bean name="handlerMapping"
       class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping"/>
    <bean name="handlerAdapter"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter"/>   

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
          destroy-method="close">

        <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
        <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
        <property name="initialSize" value="15" />
        <property name="maxActive" value="20" />
        <property name="maxWait" value="5000" />
        <property name="validationQuery" value="SELECT 1 FROM file_upload" />

        <property name="testOnBorrow" value="true" />
        <property name="testWhileIdle" value="true" />

    </bean>
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>
```

Netbeans exception trace

```
java.net.SocketException
MESSAGE: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused

STACKTRACE:

java.net.SocketException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:143)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:225)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.createNewIO(Connection.java:1805)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:452)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:411)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DriverConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverConnectionFactory.java:38)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:294)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.validateConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1247)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1221)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:880)
    at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:141)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl$NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(AbstractSessionImpl.java:292)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.getConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:157)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.connection(SessionImpl.java:550)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.doBegin(HibernateTransactionManager.java:428)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:372)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:417)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:255)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy108.findLatestClogs(Unknown Source)
    at com.bakaenterprise.server.ProfileController.findLatestClogs(ProfileController.java:66)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:686)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:827)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.bakaenterprise.util.PerformanceLog.doFilter(PerformanceLog.java:30)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1526)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1482)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)


** END NESTED EXCEPTION **


    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.createNewIO(Connection.java:1875)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:452)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:411)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DriverConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverConnectionFactory.java:38)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:294)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.validateConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1247)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1221)
    ... 56 more
```

[image]

Comment: Please provide your code also.

Comment: which code you would like me to post here? @drgPP

Comment: Do you have the password  for connection or what?

Comment: @Ali Adnan i was looking for java class from which you are trying to get your DB connection to MySql server.

Comment: @Soorapadman there is no password i am using default credentials when you install mysql on mac

Comment: @AliAdnan try to set password=""

Comment: @drgPP i am using spring to connect to mysql, i am adding springContext related code to original post

Comment: @drgPP i did, doesn't work

Comment: @drgPP added the springContext related part to original post. Thanks

Comment: @AliAdnan not sure about what socket in your url means, but can you try with the following url (if the nadeem_smartclogs is the name of your db): jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/nadeem_smartclogs

Comment: @drgPP i did, i read that somewhere on web, because if you use Sequal Pro tool and try to connect using Socket it works, even if you remove that trailing params part it doesn't work. Its kindof weird it works well on windows.

Comment: @AliAdnan are you sure you are using the jdbc driver for MAC OS?

Comment: @drgPP  Yes, downloaded the connector from the following URL

https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/

Comment: First, check whether mysql server is running and make sure you are able to connect to it using plain java (jdbc) code.

Comment: @AliAdnan very strange, may be they do not provide the version for your OS, as i see, from their site, the max version of OS is Mac OS X 10.7, and you have 10.10.2

Comment: @AliAdnan it's a worth try to use direct ip of your localhost, which is 127.0.0.1

Comment: @Soorapadman its running, i am trying to connect using Toad and Sequel Pro apps, its not working either way, it should be some JDBC configuration we may need to add.

Comment: @drgPP  Yes, i tried that with Jar as well but doesn't work, there should be some way i guess to make it work

Comment: The error indicates that the MySQL server is not running (or at least not on port 3306), or a firewall blocks the connection. This is not related to Java or the JDBC driver.

Comment: Yes it was running on 3307, thank you all for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason, MySQL on Mac OSX Yosemite listens on port 3307 and not 3306. The value is set in the LaunchDaemon, and changing the port in my.cnf has no effect. This post helped me:

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/108522/mac-os-x-10-10-mysql-5-6-26-accessible-from-cli-but-not-port-3306